# python exercise with keyboard

Tags: python-3.x

Can you please help me with one exercise. The text is: we have a mobile phone keyboard. We can use some number only if every next digit in number is neighbour of previously. for example, if we have number 8, we can use 5,7,9,0, or if we have 7, we can use only 4 and 8. The exercise is, write a function, with argument k>=1 an return the number of all k digits we can use. for example, the function with k==2 should return 26. I hope that this is understandable. I dont understand completely what this exercise want from me. And please note that this is not homework or something like that. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Create a dictionary mapping digits to possible successors, i.e. `{7: [4,8], ...}`, then write a recursive function to create all valid combinations. Try this, and come back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Please explain more `the function with k==2 should return 26` How return value becomes 26 ?

Comment: if k == 2 than how 26 ? I think it should be 1,3,5

Answer (score 2):

The key to solving this task is to use a dictionary, mapping digits to their possible successors according to the distribution of numbers on the keypad. This dictionary might loop like this:

```
succ = {1: (2, 4),      2: (1, 3, 5),      3: (2, 6),
        4: (1, 5, 7),   5: (2, 4, 6, 8),   6: (3, 5, 9),
        7: (4, 8),      8: (5, 7, 9, 0),   9: (6, 8), 
                        0: (8,)                        }
```

You do not have to align it like that, but it helps understanding. Now, you can choose how to create a function for generating all the valid combinations of numbers.

Either, you can create a recursive function, i.e. a function that calls itself again, until some "anchor" condition is reached, and then return the partial solutions "inside-out".

```
def comb_recursive(current, k):
    if len(current) >= k:
        yield current
    else:
        next = succ[current[-1]] if current else [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
        for n in next:
            for c in comb_recursive(current + [n], k):
                yield c
```

Or use an iterative approach, i.e. using a stack instead of recursion.

```
def comb_stack(k):
    stack = [[i] for i in range(10)]
    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        if len(current) >= k:
            yield current
        else:
            stack.extend([current + [n] for n in succ[current[-1]]])
```

Another variant would be first to generate *all* the combinations, and then to filter those that are valid, but while this is quite elegant and easy to comprehend, it is also a bit wasteful.

```
from itertools import product
def comb_filter(k):
    return [comb 
            for comb in product(range(10), repeat=k)
            if all(y in succ[x] for x, y in zip(comb, comb[1:]))]
```

In fact, IPython's `%timeit` shows that it's *much* slower:

```
In [13]: %timeit list(comb_recursive([], 5))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.25 ms per loop
In [14]: %timeit list(comb_stack(5))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop
In [15]: %timeit comb_filter(5)
1 loops, best of 3: 453 ms per loop
```

In any case, you can now call the function and use `len` to get the number of valid combinations.

```
>>> combs = list(comb_recursive([], 2))
>>> combs
[[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 5], [3, 2], [3, 6], [4, 1], [4, 5], [4, 7], [5, 2], [5, 4], [5, 6], [5, 8], [6, 3], [6, 5], [6, 9], [7, 4], [7, 8], [8, 5], [8, 7], [8, 9], [8, 0], [9, 6], [9, 8], [0, 8]]
>>> len(combs)
26
```

Note: If you need *only* the number of valid combinations, there might be even simpler solutions.